# Extract parameter from a string

Tags: php, string

I have to extract a string like this:

```
index.php?module=Reports&action=abc&rname=Instantpayment
```

Now my task is to extract `report`, `action` and `rname` value in PHP.

I have tried by using `explode()`, but I am not able to extract `module`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `parse_str()` in this case:

```
$string = 'index.php?module=Reports&action=abc&rname=Instantpayment';
$string = substr($string, strpos($string, '?')+1); // get the string from after the question mark until end of string
parse_str($string, $data); // use this function, stress free

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Should output:

```
Array
(
    [module] => Reports
    [action] => abc
    [rname] => Instantpayment
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `$_GET` to get query strings from the URL

```
echo $_GET['module']; //Reports
echo $_GET['action']; // abc
echo $_GET['rname'];  // Instantpayment
```

For getting from the string try `explode()`:

```
$str ='index.php?module=Reports&action=abc&rname=Instantpayment';
$e = explode('?', $str);
$e1 = explode('&', $e[1]);
foreach($e1 as $v) {
    $ex = explode('=', $v);
    $newarr[$ex[0]] = $ex[1];
}
print_r($newarr); // Use this array of values you want.
//Array ( [module] => Reports [action] => abc [rname] => Instantpayment )
echo  $newarr['module'];
echo  $newarr['action'];
echo  $newarr['rname'];
```

Comment: its a string which is extracted from  a array

Comment: Yes sir it works but how can i seprate these values. I mean how can i distinguish that this value is for module,this for action etc

Comment: check now created an arry for values use array index to get one by one like echo $newarr[1];

Comment: Ok sir i got it this will fulfill my requirement

Answer (score 4):

```
$yourUrl="module=Reports&action=abc&rname=Instantpayment"
$exploded_array = array();
parse_str($yourUrl, $exploded_array);
$exploded_array['module']; 
$exploded_array['action'];
$exploded_array['rname'];
```

Comment: Please try it on complete string

Answer (score 2):

You have to access the globale GET variable:

```
$_GET['module']
$_GET['action']
$_GET['rname']
```

Comment: dear sir,its not a url its a string how can i use $_GET for string

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $temp = "index.php?module=Reports&action=abc&rname=Instantpayment";

    $t1 = explode("=",$temp);

    for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($t1); $i++)
    {
        $temp = explode("&", $t1[$i]);
        echo $temp[0] . "\n";
    }
?>
```